# Blazor output data in html wrong encode

Tags: asp.net, blazor

The result on html viewsource:

```
    <div class="content px-4">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-dark mr-2">S&#xE0;i G&#xF2;n</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark mr-2">H&#xE0; N&#x1ED9;i</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark mr-2">V&#x169;ng T&#xE0;u</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark mr-2">&#x110;&#xE0; L&#x1EA1;t</button>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-dark mr-2">Qu&#x1EAD;n 1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark mr-2">Qu&#x1EAD;n 2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark mr-2">Qu&#x1EAD;n 10</button>
</div>
```

The result on front is ok
[image]

I dont know why this happend, and is this bad for SEO ?

Comment: Without seeing the Blazor source we can't help. Blazor is heavily tested so it creates valid markup. Almost certainly your error.

Answer (score 1):

Google will decode HTML encoded characters when building its search indexes, so this won't affect your SEO.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104072/do-characters-encoded-as-html-entities-affect-seo

As for why it happens. It does seem quite odd. Perhaps you should raise it as a bug here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues